# Location of wpa_supplicant.conf on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, wpa-supplicant

For some reason am unable to locate wpa_supplicant.conf file on my Ubuntu PC. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I did run a find and here's the result:

```
~$ sudo find / -iname wpa_supplicant.conf
[sudo] password for popo01: 
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The wpa_supplicant.conf located in dbus-1 is an xml file and looks something like this:

https://apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/trusty/main/i386/wpasupplicant/2.1-0ubuntu1/file/etc/dbus-1/system.d/wpa_supplicant.conf

This doesn't seem to be the right  wpa_supplicant.conf file.

Without the wpa_supplicant.conf, anytime I need to work with wpa_cli for establishing p2p connection between peer wifi devices, I need to kill wpa_supplicant and restart it again with my own p2p.conf file. How do I make these settings permanent? I do not want to go through the process of killing and restarting wpa_supplicant every time I boot my PC.

Answer (score 0):

`man wpa_supplicant` tells us:

```
QUICK START
       First,  make a configuration file, e.g.  /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf, that
       describes    the    networks    you    are    interested    in.     See
       wpa_supplicant.conf(5) for details.
```

By "`make a configuration file,`" the author meant "create a configuration file", and by `e.g.  /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` he/she means "for example, call the configuration file you just created `wpa_supplicant.conf`".

Since there are so many WiFi cards, and so many, many WiFi network configurations, Linux doesn't give you a default WiFi configuration.

Read `man wpa_supplicant.conf`, and create a configuration file for your configuration. Feel free to call it `wpa_supplicant.conf` (or `fred`, it doesn't matter).

Comment: Thanks Waltinator. This means there's some default config that wpa_supplicant is running with.  Is there a way I can dump or obtain those configuration? ... like a command or something? Or is it the source I need to dig into!